POSTGRESQL connection code through tomcat server. Connection is null
I am trying to create a user in my database but first I need to connect to the database.
Below is the code I am using and it works perfectly if ran natively through a main function in a java class.
private Connection getConnection(String username, String password) { //creates the connection to server for a specific database
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://<IP>/DormSystem"; // url of server, postgresql is the server type, IP is the server ip with the port its on and adds on the database specified
    try {
        // Connect to PostgreSQL database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); // actually connects using the url above and username and password for admin acc
        System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully."); // console test to prove connection succeded
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

When ever this code is triggered through the tomcat server conn is null even though the exact same code works in a main class file.
Below is the error being reported on the webpage for the server when the code is ran.
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "conn" is null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "conn" is null
    Login.SQLInterfacing.CreateUser(SQLInterfacing.java:36)
    Login.CreateUserServel.doPost(CreateUserServel.java:36)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.96

Any ideas as to what is going on?
Note I am in my final year of uni and despise this module, Service centric and cloud computing.

Cloud computing? Maybe problems related to the firewall? Are you allowing outbound traffic to the database?

Database ports are completely open in the firewall both inbound and outbound.

Do you also allow outbound traffic from the server to the database? (in case Tomcat runs on a different machine than the database)

It shouldn't matter as I have the tomcat server host machines firewall turned off allowing everything. They are on seperate machines, postgre running on a windows machine and tomcat running locally on a macbook

Ah it sees apple is lying when they say all connections are allowed. I manually allowed the 8080 port through the terminal and it all works. Quite baffling but I now have a working create user page in HTML that interacts and creates a user in my postgresql database

You're swallowing exceptions. Don't do that. DriverManager.getConnection threw an exception, and then you returned conn (which was null) anyway. Find out the actual exception that you ignored, and solve the exception.

Port 8080 needs to be opened on the tomcat host machine.
In this instance the host machine was a macbook.
echo "pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080" | sudo pfctl -ef -

This line was ran in the terminal to open the port on the machine and connection was then allowed.
